# Number of times a bigram has been seen in a list up to a point

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, n-gram

Let's say I have a text like this:

```
'he is hdajs asdas da he is not asd as da s i am a da daas you am a'
```

I have created all the bigrams from this text:

```
>>> bigrams_
[('he', 'is'), ('is', 'hdajs'), ('hdajs', 'asdas'), ('asdas', 'da'), ('da', 'he'), ('he', 'is'), ('is', 'not'), ('not', 'asd'), ('asd', 'as'), ('as', 'da'), ('da', 's'), ('s', 'i'), ('i', 'am'), ('am', 'a'), ('a', 'da'), ('da', 'daas'), ('daas', 'you'), ('you', 'am'), ('am', 'a')]
```

Now I like to create a new list of bigrams where the first element of each bigram would be a positional index that shows how many times a certain bigram from the above format has been seen up to a point in text, and the second element would be the bigram of words from the initial list. For example, in the above list, the last element `('am', 'a')` has been seen 2 times, so in the new list it would correspond to this bigram: `(2, ('am', 'a'))`. 
What would be a concise Pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: How is `'am', 'a'` seen 3 times? It only occurs twice in your text, unless am missing something here

Comment: You are right. My apologies. I meant 2 times.

Comment: Except it's only been seen previously once right, so it should be `(1, ('am', 'a'))` - unless it's the cumulative count and everything starts with `1` ?

Comment: Everything starts with one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` with a default value of a `count` object and progressively take the `next` value of that keys' counter, eg:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

dd = defaultdict(lambda: count(1))
bigrams = [('he', 'is'), ('is', 'hdajs'), ('hdajs', 'asdas'), ('asdas', 'da'), ('da', 'he'), ('he', 'is'), ('is', 'not'), ('not', 'asd'), ('asd', 'as'), ('as', 'da'), ('da', 's'), ('s', 'i'), ('i', 'am'), ('am', 'a'), ('a', 'da'), ('da', 'daas'), ('daas', 'you'), ('you', 'am'), ('am', 'a')]
with_count = [(next(dd[bigram]), bigram) for bigram in bigrams]
```

Gives you:

```
[(1, ('he', 'is')),
 (1, ('is', 'hdajs')),
 (1, ('hdajs', 'asdas')),
 (1, ('asdas', 'da')),
 (1, ('da', 'he')),
 (2, ('he', 'is')),
 (1, ('is', 'not')),
 (1, ('not', 'asd')),
 (1, ('asd', 'as')),
 (1, ('as', 'da')),
 (1, ('da', 's')),
 (1, ('s', 'i')),
 (1, ('i', 'am')),
 (1, ('am', 'a')),
 (1, ('a', 'da')),
 (1, ('da', 'daas')),
 (1, ('daas', 'you')),
 (1, ('you', 'am')),
 (2, ('am', 'a'))]
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is a good solution when I have a nested list of texts. For example, let's say I have this text `['i am i am you are he is', 'you are he is i am', 'i am you are']`, where each sentence is a separate document. I want indices to reset when starting a new string. If I write `[[(next(indexer[elem]), elem) for elem in bigram] for bigram in bigrams]`, it will keep counting and incrementing bigram indices, without resetting at the start of each new document. The last ('i', 'am') in the final list would receive an index of 4, but it's seen once in the last document.

Comment: Well yeah... `.clear()` the counter where appropriate or create new counters for specific subsections...

Comment: Thanks. So writing it with list comprehension is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Well, you could make it all into a list-comp but readability wouldn't be great. Whatever's simplest to either clear the same indexer or create a new one...

Answer (score 0):

I like @JonClements itertools `count`-based solution (+1) but I don't think `defaultdict` is necessary:

```
from itertools import count

text = 'he is hdajs asdas da he is not asd as da s i am a da daas you am a'

words = text.split()

bigrams = zip(words, words[1:])

seen = dict()

result = [(next(seen.setdefault(bigram, count(1))), bigram) for bigram in bigrams]

print(*result, sep='\n')
```

OUTPUT

```
(1, ('he', 'is'))
(1, ('is', 'hdajs'))
(1, ('hdajs', 'asdas'))
(1, ('asdas', 'da'))
(1, ('da', 'he'))
(2, ('he', 'is'))
(1, ('is', 'not'))
(1, ('not', 'asd'))
(1, ('asd', 'as'))
(1, ('as', 'da'))
(1, ('da', 's'))
(1, ('s', 'i'))
(1, ('i', 'am'))
(1, ('am', 'a'))
(1, ('a', 'da'))
(1, ('da', 'daas'))
(1, ('daas', 'you'))
(1, ('you', 'am'))
(2, ('am', 'a'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
s = 'he is hdajs asdas da he is not asd as da s i am a da daas you am a'
s1 = s.split()
new_data = list(set([(s.count(' '.join(b)), b) for b in [(s1[i], s1[i+1]) for i in range(len(s1)-1)]]))
```

Output:

```
[(2, ('am', 'a')), (1, ('da', 'daas')), (1, ('not', 'asd')), (1, ('s', 'i')), (1, ('da', 'he')), (1, ('you', 'am')), (2, ('he', 'is')), (1, ('is', 'not')), (1, ('asdas', 'da')), (1, ('asd', 'as')), (1, ('hdajs', 'asdas')), (1, ('a', 'da')), (1, ('daas', 'you')), (2, ('as', 'da')), (1, ('da', 's')), (1, ('is', 'hdajs')), (1, ('i', 'am'))]
```